# Why does $(x \to a) ≠ (x = a)$ , But $f(x \to a) = f(x = a)$

Tags: limits, functions

I am really satisfied that $(x \to a) ≠(x=a)$ and if that is not right , Then all the process of $Limits$ is dividing by zero and that is a crime.

Since $(x \to a) + h = (x=a)$ , $h ≠ 0$,So Why does $f(x \to a) = f(x = a)$ ?

**NOTE:I am talking about continuous function.**

Comment: What does it mean $(x→a)+h=(x=a), h \ne 0$ ? What we have is that the **limit** of $x+h$ is $x$ when $h \to 0$.

Comment: It is the result of the def of limit : for every $\epsilon > 0$ exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|h|< \delta$, then $|x+h -x| < \epsilon$

Comment: $x \to a$ is a number which is very very very near to $x = a$ , But it does not equal , So there is a difference between these to numbers which it is $h$

Comment: For a continuous function, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. (This is commonly used to *define* continuity.) Also, "$x\to a$" is not a number and should not be written inside $f$. Rather, we should write  $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth , That what am I asking about ? Why ?

Comment: $x \to a$ is **not** a number; it is a symbol. It is the standard way to write $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$.

Comment: It is because of the definition of continuous functions. Or are you asking us why do we define continuity this way?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth ,What do you mean by that ? ==> It is because of the definition of continuous functions

Comment: As in, the reason that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ is true for continuous functions $f$ is that this is how "continuous function" is defined.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth , Could you please give me a link of definition continuous functions ? (Video)

Comment: It should be quite easy to find videos on this with a quick search online. [Here](https://youtu.be/InDHwh1CvOg) is one.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I agree that the OP shouldn't use $f(x\to a)$ since they are obviously treating $x\to a$ as a number, but to be fair, $f(x\to a)$ is a very common shorthand for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. It's especially common in physics.

Comment: @YiFan, what? Really? That's a horrible, horrible notation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear, but perhaps emphasizing this distinction will help:

A function $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$ if (and only if) for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

We write $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Noticing the differences between the two formal definitions, we see that a function $f$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: Please focus what I am saying ,Limits tell us how function behave **around** $(x = a)$ which is the same as $(x \to a)$,I guarantee to you that $(x = a)$ is different from $(x \to a)$ because if that a is not right then we divide by zero in limit , However , What do I mean  by $x \to a$ is that a number which is very very near to $x = a$ , **But not equal it** , So they are a **different numbers** , So $f($number which is$ (x = a)) $ should not equal to $f($another number which is$ (x \to a)$

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef: “$x \to a$” is not a number!

Comment: So what is it ?

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef: It's just notation to indicate that we are computing a **limit**, and exactly what the word limit means is written in this answer.

Comment: The definition of limit merely tells us when we can write $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$; or rather say "the limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, is $L$". If $f$ is not continuous at $a$ but $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists as some finite number, then this limit tells us nothing about $f(a)$ or even if $f$ is defined at $a$. IE: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$ but $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$ is not defined when $x=0$. Another example is taking a function $f$ that is continuous at $a$ and defining a new function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x \neq a$, and $g(a)=f(a)+1$.

Comment: As for how the formal definition of limit applies to continuous functions, perhaps consider the function $f(x)=x$. So if $a \in \mathbb R$, then $f(a)=a$. Since $f$ is obviously continuous at $a$, we know $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=f(a)$. Take $\varepsilon=\frac1{10}$ and find $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. (last sentence is meant to be a trivial exercise)

Comment: You didn't understand me : go here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193491/why-lim-x-to-a-fx-fa-in-continuous-function

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively speaking, the number $$A=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ is the value that the function $f$ “should” have at the point $a$, judging by the values $f(x)$ at the surrounding points ($x \neq a$).

And $$B=f(a)$$ is of course the value that the function $f$ **does** have at the point $a$.

These two numbers $A$ and $B$ need not be equal, but **if** they are equal, **then** the function $f$ is said to be **continuous** at the point $a$.
So when you say that you are talking about continuous functions, that's just another way of saying that you are only looking at function which happen to have this particular propery that $A=B$, i.e., $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$$
(or “$f(x \to a)=f(x=a)$” in your notation, which I would not recommend).