# Why $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$ in continuous function?

Tags: limits

I asked the same question here but actually no one understood me :

> [Why does $(x \to a) ≠ (x = a)$ , But $f(x \to a) = f(x = a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193342/why-does-x-to-a-%E2%89%A0-x-a-but-fx-to-a-fx-a?noredirect=1#comment6571862_3193342) .

But here a drew a figure to understand me :
[image]

**THIS FUNCTION IS INCREASING IN EVERY EVERY LITTLE BIT CHANGE** ,So the function around $\lim_{x\to 2} ≠ g(2)$ (In the second graph which hasn't gap).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92675/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-alshareef-why-lim-x-to-a-fx-fa-in).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The limiting value implies at value infinitesimally close to a point, but still not at that point. For a continuous function, the limit would be approaching the value of function at that point. So we take the limit to be value at that point. But for a discontinuous Function,we have to be careful.

Comment: So does the slope of the the function is $f(a)$ in the continuous function ?

Comment: @MohammadAlshareef The slope is the derivative, but a continuous function [needs not be differentiable anywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: Slope is f'(a) .(if defined)

Comment: @Tojrah So infinitesimally somehow number that is not zero but we treat it as zero in addition ?

Comment: Yes. In addition we neglect it.